# get data inside of a url in android

Tags: android, json, url

i have a url that inide of this url is json code . 
i need this content to decode. for example if my url is : http://url.com
i have this json in it:

```
{ "employee":{"mesg":"username is exsist!","id":0,"name":0,"username":0,"email":0,"status":500} }
```

i need from url.com this data to put in a variable and decode this.
for decoding i dont have problem . just i need to get data from url , like file_get_contents in php .
 , thanks

NOTICE:

i use HttpClient for this solution . but it is deprecated . is another way for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IOUtils.toString(url) from [Apache Commons library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4).